# Ms Sql: import csv into msql database does not work

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am using the following code to load the csv into the database:---

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\Documents and Settings\vishu.singhvi\Desktop\5columns.csv'
INTO TABLE digite61new.copy_ENTERPRISEUSER FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY
'\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;

But its showing the error:--
Incorrect syntax near 'C:\Documents and Settings\vishu.singhvi\Desktop\5columns.csv'

Please help.

Comment: Are you running this on "MySQL" or "Microsoft SQL Server"? You tagged it with both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On SQL Server this syntax is not supported.

On MySQL I don't think it should give the error you see, but your filename is wrong.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\vishu.singhvi\\Desktop\\5columns.csv'
```

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html):

> Backslash is the MySQL escape character within strings in SQL statements, so to specify a literal backslash, you must specify two backslashes for the value to be interpreted as a single backslash